# Creating objects with different names in an array using for loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, object, nsarray, enumerate

I am using a for statement to enumerate all objects in the array. For each object in the array I want to make it so that it creates a different object each time so i can refer to different ones e.g. there are 5 string objects in an array. I use the for statement to enumerate each object and each time i want to create an nsmutablestring that contains the text @"hello"

```
for (NSString *string in array) {

 // Ignore string variable
 NSMutableString *
 // I have this problem, how do I code it so that it makes a new                                               NSMutableString with a separate name that i can specify 
 // so i can refer to it
  = [NSMutableString alloc] init];

   // More code that is not relevant

}
```

In case you did not understand here is it briefly....
In an array - 5 objects
enumerate the array and create a new object each time with a separate name so i can refer to it:
object1 
object2
object3
object4
object5

Update:

By array i mean NSArray

my problem is that it I'm adding uiimageview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to get your question...
Array objects are already uniquely identified by their index. 
Why do you need different names (NSString * pointers) ???

This could be relevant in the case when you already know how many strings there are in this array, and what each of them represent. (for example, an array of strings representing some configuration parameters for a programm... if anyone thinks of a better example :)
In this case, if you want to have a clear and distinct way to access each member of an array, you don't need different pointer names, just use int constants for indexes of the array - (declared in C macros, or in an enum for example)

Comment: but  I'm using a uiimageview and i need to refer to that specially for hidden properties and so on

Comment: Can't you just cast it from the array ?`(UIImageView *)[arrayOfImageViews objectAtIndex:YOUR_IMG_INDEX]`

Comment: typecast it? that will not work i still won't be able to access the uiimageview tasks like hidden and rect

Comment: ahh, got it, create a new variable with a typecasted array objectatindex

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for (... in ...)`, use just a standard for:

```
NSArray *oldArray;
NSMutableArray *newArray;

for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *view = [UIImageView new];
    view.tag = i;
    [newArray addObject:view];
    [view release];
}

NSLog(@"%@", newArray);
```

EDIT: Updated for comment below

Comment: but i need to refer to it in CGRectIntersectsRect

Comment: and use .hidden and things like that and since there are many 'view' that are created how will i refer to each other

Comment: @user973985 You have two options. You can do `[newArray objectAtIndex:x]` or if you add them as a subview, you can do `[myView viewWithTag:x]`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly I would use another array

```
NSMutableArray * arrayOfNewObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int n = 0; n < [array count]; n++) {
    //[array objectAtIndex:n] is original object
    [arrayOfNewObjects addObject:[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hello"]];
}
//[arrayOfNewObjects objectAtIndex:0] would be your first object
```

Comment: ok but my problem is that it is a uiimageview... would this still work

Comment: and i want to use cgrectintersectsrect to see if it intersected